# React-native expo start emulator with custom time/battery lvl/wi-fi lvl

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to start ios/android simulators with custom time/battery lvl/wi-fi lvl. How can I do it?

I need this for visual regression testing (react-native-owl), I know, I can cut image or hide status bar, but it I want to find normal solution. ))

I was looking for expo docs, react-native docs, stackoverflow, but I didn't find solution.